# Angular 2 - how to get tag attributes in ngIf function

Tags: angular

given such a template

```
<a *ngIf="canAccess()" routerLink="/adminUsers">...</a>
<a *ngIf="canAccess()" routerLink="/link2">...</a>
<a *ngIf="canAccess()" routerLink="/otherlink">...</a>
<a *ngIf="canAccess()" routerLink="/somthingelse">...</a>
```

and a function:

```
canAccess()
{
    ...
```

how do I get

- the router link
- any other tag attribute inside that function

thanks

Comment: by **tag attributes** what your referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a directive and it's associated component, so I just give it the module the user wants to access

that directive asks a service if user is logged and can access that link

if yes, the link is remplaced with the component

here is an exemple on how to insert component dynamicaly (not containing the authorization part)

```
import { Directive, Input, ComponentFactoryResolver,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItemComponent } from './menuItem.component';

@Directive({ selector: '[menuItem]' })
export class MenuItemDirective {

    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

    @Input() set menuItem(_link: string) {
        if(some sort of condition depending on a auth service)
        {
            const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MenuItemComponent);
            const menuItemComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
            menuItemComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
        else
            this.viewContainer.clear();
  }
}
```

might be overkill, but in the end I use

```
<a *menuItem="dashBoard"></a>
```

instead of

```
<a class="menuItemA menuRouterLinkA" routerLink="/dashBoard" routerLinkActive="menuCurrentLinkA" >{{ "DashBoard" }}</a>
```

and it deals with features/page/modules.. access authorisation :-)

yay

Answer (score 1):

Update your template

```
   <a *ngIf="canAccess($event)" routerLink="/adminUsers">...</a>
```

and your component

```
 canAccess(event){

    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(event.currentTarget.getAttribute("routerlink"));
    ..
    }
```

Comment: You just need to check the `event.currentTarget.getAttribute('routerlink')` in your `canAccess()` method via if/switch/array.includes/whatever and return the corresponding boolean.

Comment: oh I did not know I could pass $event like for clicks, nice indeed, thanks

Comment: your welcome, but you need care `currentTarget` will not work in some browsers. In that case it maybe `srcElement` or `target`

Answer (score 0):

You might need:

- [Location](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html#!#path-anchor) to get the current URL.
- [UrlSegment](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSegment-class.html) if you want to check URL parameters.

Put the ones you need into the constructor and call their methods in your `canAccess()`.

In addition you could protect your route (from `routerLink`) itself with a [Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guard-admin-feature).

Comment: but I have many links, I just gave one as an example(I updated my template)

Comment: So in order to use Guards you need to add them in your `app.routes.ts` (or wherever you have them).

Comment: guards can only block access to module, but how do I check if I can display my link or not ? maybe write a directive that I would use for each link that checks if it can be displayed ?

Comment: Well, for check if something should be displayed: use *ngIf. Inside the *ngif you have to check for a boolean or something is inside an array or whatever. If its true => its displayed. For example I used an array of objects that represented the links of a menu. These objects also may have a property like a boolean or integer, that stands for its visibility under specific circumstances. But the implementation depends on your needs.

Comment: the whole idea behind my post is to do that precisely, but it would be easier if I could pass to the function I call in the ngif, the url of the link without writong it wice

Comment: like <a *ngIf="canAccess('/adminUsers')" routerLink="/adminUsers">...</a> which I wanted to avoid...I mean there must be a way to get the routerLink attributes of the html tag, from the canAccess function